# Is it possible to put track markers in between tracks in one large audio file so that an audio player will treat the file as a CD?

Tags: mp3, vlc, markers

Here's what I mean:

I have several songs stored as individual mp3 files.

I have amalgamated them into one large mp3 file.

When I play the file with VLC or any other piece of audio player software, the entire file just plays from start to finish as expected.

If I press the "next track" button, the right facing arrow next to a vertical line, the player software just starts the entire file from the beginning again.

What I want to do is put some kind of marker in between the individual tracks so that after I amalgamate them into one big audio file the audio player software will interpret pressing the "next track" button to mean "jump to the next track".

Essentially, what I want to do is somehow "trick" the audio player software into interpreting my single audio file comprised of amalgamated  files as a CD with the typical "next track" button interface.

How can I do this?

I'm not committed to the MP3 format.

If I can get this to work with another format, that's fine as long as that format is common enough to be played by the major pieces of audio file player software e.g. VLC, Windows player, etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Matroska supports chapter markers, which you can use for this purpose.

See also:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/49289504/362536

Comment: Yeah, but that looks like video editing software. Does it handle MP3's etc.?

Comment: Matroska is a container format which handles most any codec and stream.

Comment: OK. But, after I place the markers in and combine the files into one large file, which player can I use to play the file? Will VLC work?

Comment: Yes, VLC will work just fine.  Rather than assuming what people tell you won't work, consider trying it first.  :-)

Comment: I'm using MKVToolNix to merge several .flac files. The program mergers the files OK, but doesn't put in the chapter markers. So, when I press the next track button, I get the same problem as before - the entire track just starts from the beginning again instead of jumping to the next song.